# How can I deploy a ClickOnce application via Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, clickonce

We're in the need of deploying a .NET clickonce application through an Apacke Tomcat 6. server. Does anyone have any tips or caveats for setting this up ? (Or is ist just so straight foreward I don't even need to ask ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ClickOnce is just a static file, prepared in a specified format. The clickonce file uses a special MimeType mapping, namely

```
application/x-ms-application
```

To configure this in tomcat, either in the `$TOMCAT/conf/web.xml` or the web context,

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>application</extension>
   <mime-type>application/x-ms-application</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Alternatively, if you use Apache in front of Tomcat to accelerate static files, you can add the mime type mapping like this in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file

```
AddType application/x-ms-application .application
```